# Special join of four columns into new two ones in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-manipulation

I work in **R** and I have the interesting problem.
I want to transform next data frame:

```
DF = data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3),
              Person1 = c("Devin Davey", "Rui Butt", "Keon Dotson"),
              Sign = "artist",
              Person2 = c("Eli Greer", "Alvin Simons", "Leona Ford"),
              Sex = c("female", "male", "female"),
              Score = c(10, 20, 30)) 



  ID     Person1   Sign      Person2    Sex Score
1  1 Devin Davey artist    Eli Greer female    10
2  2    Rui Butt artist Alvin Simons   male    20
3  3 Keon Dotson artist   Leona Ford female    30
```

To format like this:

```
  ID         Name   Sign Score
1  1  Devin Davey artist    10
2  1    Eli Greer female    10
3  2     Rui Butt artist    20
4  2 Alvin Simons   male    20
5  3  Keon Dotson artist    30
6  3   Leona Ford female    30
```

That is, there is a special join of four columns into two new ones.

I have an idea to do it as follows:

```
PART1 <- DF %>% 
            select(ID, Person1, Person2, Score) %>%
            gather(key, Name, -c(ID, Score), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
            select(-key) %>%
            arrange(ID) %>%
            mutate(temp_id = 1:n())

PART2 <- DF %>% 
            select(ID, Sign, Sex) %>%
            gather(key, Sign, -ID, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
            select(-key) %>%
            arrange(ID) %>%
            mutate(temp_id = 1:n())

PART1 %>%
        left_join(PART2, by = c("ID" = "ID", "temp_id" = "temp_id")) %>%
        select(-temp_id) %>%
        relocate(Score, .after = Sign)
```

But it seems to me that such a solution is not very beautiful, and I think this problem can be solved in the better way.

Therefore, I will be grateful for your ideas on solving this problem using `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could explicitly select the column names and use `bind_rows`

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(DF %>% select(ID, Name = Person1, Sign = Sex, Score),
          DF %>% select(ID, Name = Person2, Sign, Score)) %>% 
  arrange(ID)
#>   ID         Name   Sign Score
#> 1  1  Devin Davey female    10
#> 2  1    Eli Greer artist    10
#> 3  2     Rui Butt   male    20
#> 4  2 Alvin Simons artist    20
#> 5  3  Keon Dotson female    30
#> 6  3   Leona Ford artist    30
```

or `full_join`

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% select(ID, Name = Person1, Sign = Sex, Score) %>% 
  full_join(DF %>% select(ID, Name = Person2, Sign, Score)) %>% 
  arrange(ID)
#> Joining, by = c("ID", "Name", "Sign", "Score")
#>   ID         Name   Sign Score
#> 1  1  Devin Davey female    10
#> 2  1    Eli Greer artist    10
#> 3  2     Rui Butt   male    20
#> 4  2 Alvin Simons artist    20
#> 5  3  Keon Dotson female    30
#> 6  3   Leona Ford artist    30
```

Answer (score 4):

We can change the names from 'Sign', 'Sex' to a common name 'Sign' with a sequence appended as suffix to match those with Person and then use `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>% 
   rename_at(vars(c('Sign', 'Sex')), ~ c('Sign1', 'Sign2')) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -c(ID, Score), names_to = c(".value", "grp"), 
        names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=\\d)") %>%
   select(ID, Name = Person, Sign, Score)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#     ID Name         Sign   Score
#  <dbl> <chr>        <chr>  <dbl>
#1     1 Devin Davey  artist    10
#2     1 Eli Greer    female    10
#3     2 Rui Butt     artist    20
#4     2 Alvin Simons male      20
#5     3 Keon Dotson  artist    30
#6     3 Leona Ford   female    30
```

Answer (score 4):

In base R you could use the function `reshape`. Since this gives a different ordering, we will reorder to get the exact data as depicted above. Though not necessary

```
DF1<-reshape(DF, matrix(2:5, 2), dir="long")
DF1[order(DF1$ID),c("ID", "Person1","Sign", "Score")]

    ID      Person1   Sign Score
1.1  1  Devin Davey artist    10
1.2  1    Eli Greer female    10
2.1  2     Rui Butt artist    20
2.2  2 Alvin Simons   male    20
3.1  3  Keon Dotson artist    30
3.2  3   Leona Ford female    30
```